# Command scheduled with `at` fails but gives no error

Tags: linux, bash, at

I recently learned about the `at` command in Unix system.

Let's say I want a Python script (that might crash) to run 2 hours after I launch it. I do something like this:

```bash
$ echo python3 my_script.py | at now + 2hours
```

I have few questions:

1. Is it the correct way to do it?
2. How can I capture any logs? Because if the script fails, `at` doesn't inform me, and I don't have access to the error.
3. I really want to use `at` because it makes my life so much easier, but is it really meant to do that? Should I use another tool?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it the correct way to do it?

Yes, basically. `at` is the right tool and [it should work even after you log out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/327181/108618).

---

> How can I capture any logs?

The [POSIX specification of `at`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html) states [emphasis mine]:

> `-m`
>
> Send mail to the invoking user after the at-job has run, announcing its completion. Standard output and standard error produced by the at-job shall be mailed to the user as well, unless redirected elsewhere. Mail shall be sent even if the job produces no output.
>
> **If `-m` is not used, the job's standard output and standard error shall be provided to the user by means of mail, unless they are redirected elsewhere; if there is no such output to provide, the implementation need not notify the user of the job's completion.**

Either make sure you can receive mail, then check mail when the time comes; or redirect.

<sup>("When the time comes" means "after the job completes". Depending on what you are going to run, you may or may not be able to tell in advance how long it will take. Your `at` when invoked as `at -l` may (or may not) show you jobs currently running. Read `man 1 at`.)</sup>

`at` uses "a separate invocation of the shell". A command you pipe to `at` will be interpreted as shell code. This means you can specify redirections there. Example:

```
echo 'python3 my_script.py >>/path/to/log 2>&1' | at now + 2hours
```

Another example, this one logs timestamps before and after the actual command and uses a here document instead of `echo`:

```
at now + 2hours <<EOF
{
echo start
date
python3 my_script.py
echo "$?"
date
echo finish
} >/path/to/log 2>&1
EOF
```

Note if the redirection fails then an error message stating this fact will be mailed to you (and the shell code in `{ }` won't be executed); so it's good to receive and check mail anyway.

---

> if the script fails, `at` doesn't inform me

In general it's not "if the job fails". `at` will make no attempt to inform you by mail if you don't use `-m` and the job prints nothing to (not redirected) stdout and nothing to (not redirected) stderr. The job being silent is what matters, the exit status of the job is irrelevant.

Furthermore the exit status of the job is not reported (at least in my Debian).

In the example above I included `echo "$?"`. This is how you can get the exit status of `python3 my_script.py`.

---

> is it [i.e. `at`] really meant to do that?

Yes, that behavior is by design. You may call it not-the-best design if you want, but note each job is run in a separate process group with no controlling terminal, so it can work even after you log out; this is a huge advantage sometimes. Mail is a good way to reach user who may be logged out at the moment.

Still, because you give *shell code* to `at`, you can easily pass multiple commands and use redirections, thus fully customize what is printed where and not rely on mail (mail can still be useful in case of erroneous redirection(s)).

---

> Should I use another tool?

It's up to you. In my opinion there is probably no need. `at` is a well established and standard tool. Maybe there are limitations of `at` that can be reasons to want a better tool, but the problem in question should not be seen as one of them, because it can easily be solved, as shown above.

Additionally in *nix there are general ways to customize commands. Examples:

- `alias at='at -m'` will automatically add `-m` to `at` commands in your shell. This way you can force `at` to send mail unconditionally and you do it without typing `-m` each time.
- This shell function:

  ```
  atl () (
  (printf "exec >'%s' 2>&1\n" "$LOG"; cat) | at "$@"
  )
  ```

  will allow you to do:

  ```
  echo python3 my_script.py | LOG=/path/to/log atl now + 2hours
  ```

  The above function is a proof of concept, **it's potentially unsafe**. If expanded `$LOG` contains single-quotes then it will misbehave. If the value of `$LOG` is not under your total control then undesired (or even rogue) code can be executed. To easily fix, use `%q` instead of `'%s'`; xor (in Bash) use `%s` instead of `'%s'` and "${LOG@Q}"`instead of`"$LOG"`. These methods are not portable though. Other shells may give you similar possibilities. A modified function that should work in Bash:

  ```
  atl () {
  (printf "exec >%s 2>&1\n" "${LOG@Q}"; cat) | at "$@"
  }
  ```

With this knowledge please answer "should I use another tool?" for yourself.

Comment: And don't forget,l but `atd` _must_ also be running, else nothing will happen.

Comment: You might want to explain that the email delivery isn't necessarily to their email address, but is quite likely to be to the local user account